# different tic toc results in one-time run or run in steps

Tags: matlab, time

i confront with a weird fact! i wrote a matlab code that compare runing time of two algorithms. i embrace codes of each algorithm by tic toc functions, so i can compare time complexities of them. but weird thing is here:
if i run the script at once, algorithm 1 has longer time than algorithm 2, but if i put breakmarks after each toc, algorithm 1 would has shorter time! 
in order to understand better what I said, consider following:

```
tic
% some matlab codes implementing algorithm1
time1 = toc;
disp(['t1 = ',num2str(time1)])   % here is the place for first breakpoint

tic
% some matlab codes implementing algorithm2
time2 = toc;
disp(['t2 = ',num2str(time2)])    % here is the place for second breakpoint
```

can anyone please explain to me why this happen? thanks

Comment: For what length time span?

Comment: Both algorithms run time is of order milisecond approximately

Comment: Timing code that executes that quickly with a single run of `tic/toc` is not going to yield useful results. [MATLAB's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html) recommends that code being timed with `tic/toc` take longer than `0.1` seconds. You should use [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) or run the code to be timed with `tic/toc` in a loop and take the average across all iterations (`timeit` does this internally).

Comment: In fact I do a mont carlo run and take the average time of each code block. And I know that first algorithm is of order O(t^2) and second is of order O(t^3). Without loop exec and by putting breakpoints times is so , But average time with mont carlo and with no breakpoints opposed that!

Comment: It is never a good idea to combine debugging and timing operations. Debugging really slows down your execuion.